# jQuery set cookies to post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cookies

How is it possible to set cookie to post method in jQuery ajax method?

My code is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://myUrl",
    data: "data",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
});
```

I want to put there cookies but not from current session, just as `String` (I get it from another website), tried to add something like:

```
cookie: "myCookies",
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the custom cookie on cross-domain requests,
try to use this code. it sets the own domain's cookies:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "URL",
   data: "data",
   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   },
   contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to set different cookie? Something else than jQuery?

Comment: you cannot set different cookie using javascript in the browser, it is the security policy. you can set the cookie for request to 'domain.com' only if this cookie was received from 'domain.com'. There's a few workaround's, but they are hard to implement

Comment: Could you put some 'key-words' and let me search?

Answer (score 0):

Why You want that cookie?

You could either use sessionStorage or localStorage if you just wanna track the data in the current session.

Comment: i want to get data from website from authenticated is needed and have access only for cookies

Comment: Have you tried the @Goolishka code 

   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   },